# array of char arrays indices are wrong order - simple

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I have a simple question problem, yet it's been causing me a lot of trouble.

I'm writing a checkers program in C#.

This is the code that is responsible for generating buttons on the screen:

```
    for (ButtonRowindex = 0; ButtonRowindex < m_BoardSize; ButtonRowindex++)
    {
        for (ButtonColindex = 0; ButtonColindex < m_BoardSize; ButtonColindex++)
        {
            m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex] = new Button();
            m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Size = new Size(SizeOfButton, SizeOfButton);
            m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Left = 10 + ButtonRowindex * SizeOfButton;
            m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Top = 50 + ButtonColindex * SizeOfButton;
            if ((ButtonRowindex + ButtonColindex) % 2 == 0)
            {
                m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Enabled = false;
                m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
            m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Text = string.Format("{0}", counter);
            counter++;
            this.Controls.Add(m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex]);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it seems to be entering them in the wrong order. This is the order in which they enter:

[image]

and that creates a big problem because throughout the code im trying to access element i,j but actually its giving me j,i, and i dont want to switch my code everywhere just because of this simple problem.

Why is this happening? how can this be fixed?

My biggest problem is that button i,j in the windows form is NOT button i,j in my m_PlayButtonArray. That is a huge problem.

Comment: Next time can you crop the screenshot to the form only.

Comment: Why not use a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Left = 10 + ButtonRowindex * SizeOfButton;
 m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Top = 50 + ButtonColindex * SizeOfButton;
```

to

```
 m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Left = 10 + ButtonColindex * SizeOfButton;
 m_PlayButtonArray[ButtonRowindex, ButtonColindex].Top = 50 + ButtonRowindex * SizeOfButton;
```

Comment: GENIUS! Thank you! my god that was simple. What an oversight. Thank you so very much sir.